# I cannot run Daydream ndk sample Controller Paint

Tags: android-ndk, daydream

I am getting started with Google Daydream C++ apps (NDK). I am following the steps to run the Controller Paint App from this official guide

https://developers.google.com/vr/android/ndk/get-started

At the beginning I've opened ndk/demos/controllerpaint as the guide says but this way Android Studio did not recognise it as a project so I've imported the entire gvr-android-sdk folder and things looks much better. However **ndk-controllerpaint is still not appearing as a target app**.

Does anyone experience this?

Note: I'm using GVR Android SDK v1.60.0 which is only two days ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some hours I've realised that there are a few steps that may be easily overlooked

1. As I wrote in the question does not import ndk/demos/controllerpaint directory to AS but the entire cloned directory (gvr-android-sdk)
2. Run ./gradlew :extractNdk as explained in "Treasure Hunt sample app" section
3. Uncomment this line in settings.gradle

   include ':samples:ndk-controllerpaint'
4. Rebuild (or re-open the project)
5. Now ndk-controllerpaint is in the target app list and is able to run

Hope it helps someone else

Comment: Thanks for the help! The only thing to add is if it complains about `google()` you need to run a gradle of version 4.1 or higher by setting `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4.1-all.zip` in `gradle-wrapper.properties`